# understanding how to add a column without having to grouping by it in sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    status,
    CASE
        WHEN status = 0 THEN 'bla' 
        WHEN status = 2 THEN 'bla1'  
    END AS "description" ,
    COUNT(*) AS total     
FROM
    TRANSACTIONS 
WHERE 
    status != 1 
GROUP BY
    status
```

which displays:

| Status | DESCRIPTION | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | bla | 29 |
| 2 | bla1 | 70 |
| 3 | (null) | 12 |
| 4 | (null) | 85 |

now lets assume I have a table called `Status_Codes` which provides the Description itself, for example:

| Status | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | bla |
| 2 | bla1 |

I want to remove the case statement from my query that explicitly attaching the descriptions I need, and add my FROM clause the `Status_Codes` table, and to add `Status_Codes.Description` to my select.
That action cannot be done simply because I use an aggregate function in my select statement and I'd have to group by the same column( which is not something I want).
Im not sure on how to approach that problem, was thinking maybe it has something to do with partition by, but even if thats the case I dont know how to implement it in my query.

Any advices, Enlightments and whatnot will be appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why that irrational *fear* of adding yet another column into the `group by` clause? That's the simplest and most efficient way of doing it.

```
  SELECT t.status, c.description, COUNT (*) AS total
    FROM transactions t JOIN status_codes c ON c.status = t.status
   WHERE t.status != 1
GROUP BY t.status, c.description
```

What benefit do you expect if you do it differently?

BTW, if you have `group by` clause, you don't need `distinct`.

Comment: I was trying to do that it made my result table change somewhy. well Indeed I was doing something wrong and ur solution works. thanks !

Comment: On a side note: To put the description in the group by clause is only necessary in Oracle (and some other DBMS, too). As there is just one description per status, it would suffice to group by status alone. This is called functional dependency. Oracle is just not yet capable of handling this.

Comment: As I don't know any other database, I didn't even know that such a thing exists. Thank you, @Thorsten!